# Split table in multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to split long tables in multiple pages (if possible with a caption like "to be continued on next page").

I found kableExtra to look promising, however this seems to be connected to R and I really have no idea how to implement that into my current latex environment, which is why I was wondering if there's a more simple way?

Here's my MWE (sorry it's long - that's why I really need to split the table :D )

```
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPILING SORTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
% arara: bib2gls: { group: true }
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
% arara: makeindex: { style: mind.ist }
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
% [arara:] clean: { extensions: [ aux, bbl, bcf, blg, ltjruby, run.xml, synctex.gz, glg, glstex, idx, ilg, ind, lof, log, lot, out, toc ] }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}% table ssf
  {\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}% figure ssf
  {\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
   \@float{figure}}
  {\end@float}
\makeatother

\usepackage[match,MogaHMinEx90]{luatexja-preset}% Japanese
\setmainjfont{MogaHMinEx90}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}% hiragana
\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-3}}% punctuation is Latin
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGING TITLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\mbox{\thesection.\enskip$|$\enskip}}% 

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,% positive value, if afterindent=false is set
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.}% replace \autodot by a fixed dot for section entries
   ]{section}
   
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
  
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
  
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{paragraph}
  
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subparagraph}
  \usepackage{authblk}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TOC
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}% correct TOC count for tables
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}}}% TOC in bookmarks
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GLOSSARIES & INDECES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
 abbreviations,% create 'abbreviations' glossary
 style=indexgroup,% set the default style to 'tree'
 postdot
]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short}% set abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossary}]
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont\bfseries}% set serif style glossary
\makeindex
\usepackage[totoc]{idxlayout}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*\appendixmore{
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}% longtables 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}% mark text
\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{diagbox}% diagonal box
\usepackage{multirow}% multirow for diagonal box 
\usepackage{tikz}% tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\aboverulesep}
\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\belowrulesep}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\ADLnullwidehline

\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{longtable}{ll >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm} >{\raggedright}p{3cm} cr} 
\caption{Kollokationen von 禍} \\
%\toprule
\textbf{Syntax} & \textbf{Kollokation} & \textbf{Kana} & 
\textbf{Translat} & \textbf{Frequenz} & \textbf{Score}  \\ 
%\arrayrulecolor{black}
\midrule
\endhead

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} wo + Verb & &  & & 15  & 11,0 \\ 
  & 転ずる  & tenzuru & wenden & 11  & 11,8 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぼす  & oyobosu & ausüben & 4 & 10,2 \\ 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Pron. + no & &  & & 23  & 10,2 \\ 

  & 鳥 & tori  & Vogel  & 2 & 11,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 洪水   & kōzui & Überschwemmung & 2 & 10,9 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 虫 & mushi & Insekt & 1 & 10,3 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 人滿   &  & Menschenmenge & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 所謂政教混乱 & iwayuru seikyō konran & s.\ g.\ politisch-religiöse Verwirrung  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 生民   & seimin  & Volk   & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 子孫赤族 & shison aka-zoku  & Nachkomme der Akha  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 破船   & hasen & Schiffbruch  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 国家党人 & kokka tōjin & Parteimitglied & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 東夷北狄 & tōi hokuteki & Dongyi und Beidi~(indigene Völker Chinas)  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 連累   & renrui  & Mitschuld  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 江浙   & kōnan & Jiangzhe~(hist. Region Chinas, ca.\ 1276--1299) & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 文字   & moji  & Schrift(zeichen) & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 代々弑殺 & daidai shīsatsu  & & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 滔天   & tōten & Tōten (pol. Aktivist, $\approx$1871--1922) & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 宦者   & kanja & Eunuch & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 不思議  & fushigi & Mysterium  & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 先達て  & sakidachite & zuvor  & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 外寇   & gaikō & Invasion   & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 孛佛兵争 & haifutsu heisō & Deutsch-Französischer Krieg (1870--1871) & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 人為   & jin'i & menschliches Tun & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} ni + Verb & &  & & 10  & 10,8 \\ 

  & 逢う   & au & sich begegnen & 3 & 11,5 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 罹る   & kakaru  & erleiden   & 4 & 11,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 堪ざる  & koezaru & (nicht) aushalten & 1 & 10,7 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 陥る   & ochiiru & in etw. (ver)fallen & 1 & 10,5 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 當る   & ataru & treffen & 1 & 10,3 \\ 

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} wa + Verb & &  & & 11  & 10,8 \\ 

  & 起こる  & okoru & sich ereignen & 4 & 11,9 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 伏蔵為る & fukuzō suru & sich verborgen halten & 1 & 10,9 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 有る得る & arueru  & möglich sein & 1 & 10,8 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 局為る  & kyokusuru & begrenzen  & 1 & 10,8 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぶ   & oyobu & sich erstrecken  & 2 & 10,7 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 避ける  & sakeru  & (ver)meiden  & 1 & 10,5 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 関する  & kansuru & betreffen  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Adn & &  & & 1 & 10,6 \\ 

  & 然したる & sashitaru & nicht sonderlich & 1 & 10,9 \\ 

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} no + Pronomen & &  & & 7 & 7,1  \\ 

  & 門 & monkado & Tor    & 3 & 12,3 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 根源   & kongen  & Ursprung   & 1 & 10,4 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 身 & mi & Körper & 1 & 10,4 \\ 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Kompositum    & &  & & 1 & 13,4 \\ 

  & 仏郎察  & futsu rō satsu & Frankreich & 1 & 13,4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is now giving me a hard time to adjust the order for these so they dont conflict each other.

```
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}% mark text
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}% tikz
```

With this setup as above it does work, however for some reason the first field "Syntax" is blacked out.
Any idea how I can fix this?

[image: here]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you replace the `table/tabular` combination of environments with a [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) environment. The resulting table spans about 3-1/2 pages.

For the following example code, I had to guess as to one should load a font that can display Japanase kanji. I chose the `fontspec` package and the free (as in free of charge) `Noto Serif CJK JP` font. You're obviously free to make other choices.

A final suggestion (not implemented in the code below): I think all instances of

```
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
```

can (should?) be deleted or commented out. FWIW, I've already commented out most `\hline` directives, as they don't do anything useful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}


% -----
% Fonts
% -----

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK JP} % or some other suitable font


%---------
%   TABLES
%---------

\usepackage{longtable} % <-- new

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{diagbox}% diagonal box
\usepackage{multirow}% multirow for diagonal box 

%--------
%   MAIN
%--------

\begin{document}
   
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\aboverulesep}
\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\belowrulesep}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\ADLnullwidehline

\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{longtable}{ll >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm} >{\raggedright}p{3cm} cr} 
\caption{Kollokationen von 禍} \\
%\toprule
\textbf{Syntax} & \textbf{Kollokation} & \textbf{Kana} & 
\textbf{Translat} & \textbf{Frequenz} & \textbf{Score}  \\ 
%\arrayrulecolor{black}
\midrule
\endhead

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} wo + Verb & &  & & 15  & 11,0 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 転ずる  & tenzuru & wenden & 11  & 11,8 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぼす  & oyobosu & ausüben & 4 & 10,2 \\ 
%\hline
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Pron. + no & &  & & 23  & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 鳥 & tori  & Vogel  & 2 & 11,1 \\ 
\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 洪水   & kōzui & Überschwemmung & 2 & 10,9 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 虫 & mushi & Insekt & 1 & 10,3 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 人滿   &  & Menschenmenge & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 所謂政教混乱 & iwayuru seikyō konran & s.\ g.\ politisch-religiöse Verwirrung  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 生民   & seimin  & Volk   & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 子孫赤族 & shison aka-zoku  & Nachkomme der Akha  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 破船   & hasen & Schiffbruch  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 国家党人 & kokka tōjin & Parteimitglied & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 東夷北狄 & tōi hokuteki & Dongyi und Beidi~(indigene Völker Chinas)  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 連累   & renrui  & Mitschuld  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 江浙   & kōnan & Jiangzhe~(hist. Region Chinas, ca.\ 1276--1299) & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 文字   & moji  & Schrift(zeichen) & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 代々弑殺 & daidai shīsatsu  & & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 滔天   & tōten & Tōten (pol. Aktivist, $\approx$1871--1922) & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 宦者   & kanja & Eunuch & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 不思議  & fushigi & Mysterium  & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 先達て  & sakidachite & zuvor  & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 外寇   & gaikō & Invasion   & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 孛佛兵争 & haifutsu heisō & Deutsch-Französischer Krieg (1870--1871) & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 人為   & jin'i & menschliches Tun & 1 & 10,1 \\ 
%\hline
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} ni + Verb & &  & & 10  & 10,8 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 逢う   & au & sich begegnen & 3 & 11,5 \\ 
\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 罹る   & kakaru  & erleiden   & 4 & 11,2 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 堪ざる  & koezaru & (nicht) aushalten & 1 & 10,7 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 陥る   & ochiiru & in etw. (ver)fallen & 1 & 10,5 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 當る   & ataru & treffen & 1 & 10,3 \\ 
%\hline
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} wa + Verb & &  & & 11  & 10,8 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 起こる  & okoru & sich ereignen & 4 & 11,9 \\ 
\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 伏蔵為る & fukuzō suru & sich verborgen halten & 1 & 10,9 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 有る得る & arueru  & möglich sein & 1 & 10,8 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 局為る  & kyokusuru & begrenzen  & 1 & 10,8 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぶ   & oyobu & sich erstrecken  & 2 & 10,7 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 避ける  & sakeru  & (ver)meiden  & 1 & 10,5 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 関する  & kansuru & betreffen  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
%\hline
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Adn & &  & & 1 & 10,6 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 然したる & sashitaru & nicht sonderlich & 1 & 10,9 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor{black}%\hline
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} no + Pronomen & &  & & 7 & 7,1  \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 門 & monkado & Tor    & 3 & 12,3 \\ 
\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 根源   & kongen  & Ursprung   & 1 & 10,4 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\cline{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cdashline{2-6}
  & 身 & mi & Körper & 1 & 10,4 \\ 
%\hline
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Kompositum    & &  & & 1 & 13,4 \\ 
\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}%\hline
  & 仏郎察  & futsu rō satsu & Frankreich & 1 & 13,4 \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! @Mico that actually worked really well! I only have one additional question. I usually write the reference below tables, but if I do that in your MWE I would need to write that after \end{longtable} right? In that case, there's a risk the text might float somewhere below the next table isn't it? Is there a way to avoid that or rather make sure the text below sticks with the table end?

Comment: @user236381 - Not really. Just change `\arrayrulecolor{black} \bottomrule \endlastfoot` to `\arrayrulecolor{black} \bottomrule <more stuff here> \endlastfoot`. Just keep in mind that you're still inside the `longtable` environment. Depending on what "more stuff here" consists of, you may need to encase the stuff in a `\multicolumn{6}{p{\textwidth}}{...}` wrapper.

Comment: thank you! worked!

Comment: One more question (super sorry!)If I add \multicolumn{6}{p{\textwidth}}{Eigene Darstellung} to the code it will overlap a tiny bit (which I can fix by using 1pt instead of 4pt at \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
however, something I also noticed is that the last column seems to be pretty big (a lot bigger than I would assume judging from the fact there is only a number entered)

Comment: (updated in main question)

Comment: @user236381 - Not sure I understand the latest comment. AFAICT, the update consisted of adding a screenshot. Or am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: thank you! the update consisted of amendments in the code as per your suggestions as well as the output screenshot. as you can see, the table overlaps slightly on the right and the range (width) of the row on the right ("score") seems to be quite big.

Comment: @user236381 - I'm not sure how your updated code is supposed to be compiled, as there appears to be no information as to the choice of fonts that can generate the kanjis. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry! Added it in the main file. I use lualatex and luatexja package

Comment: @user236381 - I take it that you've considered changing `\setlength\tabcolsep{4 pt}` to, say, `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}`, but for some reason have decided against this course of action. I don't have the font `MogaHMinEx90` installed on my system (MacOS 11.4 "Big Sur", MacTex2021), and the websites that appear to carry the font are unintelligible to me. (I can't read Japanese, sorry.) I'm therefore not in a position to help you further. Do you want me to delete this answer as it is evidently of no use to you? Please advise.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can live with the fact of it overlapping a bit, however after trying again, the first field gets blacked out (edited in question above). This is probably unrelated to the Japanese font, thus you can probably use your font as well. :)

Comment: Since the actual question was solved but raised other issues I will close this one and create a new ticket. Thank you!